# Redirect to .aspx page with a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a web forms .aspx page that usually handles get requests and simply displays some content.. nothing fancy. I have a new case where sometimes, I would need to redirect to this page but also send a file. Could I simply do this as a POST request and write the file to the body of the request, or is this bad practice?
I could write the file to a NAS before redirecting and then have my .aspx page read from the NAS once it gets the request but that seems expensive.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would obviously need to do some file validation on the server, but if you're using actual file upload methods, then you should have access to the `Request.Files` object to process the file upload further.